# Как сделать треугольник паскаля ровным?

Tags: java

Здравствуйте, можете подсказать , как сделать  треугольник паскаля  ровным, т.е. равносторонним ?
Если можно, то показать в виде кода, т.к. что именно надо сделать понимаю, но не знаю как это написать. Заранее спасибо.

тр. паскаля:

```
public class PascalTriangle {
    public static final int strings = 20; 

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] s = new int [strings] [];
        s[0] = new int[1]; 
        System. out. println  (s [0] [0] = 1);
        s[1] = new int[2];  
        s[1][0] = s[1][1] = 1; 
        System.out.println( s[1][0] + " " + s[1][1]  );  
        for (int i = 2; i < strings; i++){  
            s[i] = new int[i+1]; 
            System.out.print(( s[i][0] = 1) + " ");
            for (int j = 1; j < i; j++) 
                System.out. print ( (s[i] [j] = s[i-1][j-1] + s[i-1][j]) + " ");

            System.out. println (s [i] [i]  =  1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Равносторонним не получится, т. к. sqrt(3)/2 — иррациональное число. Получится только равнобедренный.

А что именно вы хотите сделать? Опишите это, и опишите, где встретилась трудность.

Comment: Видимо проблема в том что при выводе все съезжает в одну кучу, можно попробовать получить позицию самой верхней единичке по отношению к количеству символов в нижней.

Comment: VladD,упс, извиняюсь, и правда не получится. Как я понимаю , нужно при выводе выводить сначала пробелы, а потом число, а потом опять пробелы , а число пробелов- функция от номера ряда ,предельный номер ряда - номер ряда и все это пополам. столько в начале,столько же в конце. Но я не знаю как это написать,т.к. знакома только с паскалем (около месяца) на среднем уровне , а с java и c++ только знакомлюсь.

Comment: @ace9000: Не, знать, что выводить пробелы недостаточно. Подумайте над тем, **сколько** пробелов надо выводить в первой строке? Во второй? В третьей? В `i`-ой?

А программирование на этом уровне везде одинаковое, что на Java, что на паскале.

Comment: Чтобы посчитать количество пробелов можно перед выводом на экран печатать каждую строку треугольника в строковую переменную. Но красивей всего будет если посчитать длину самого большого числа в треугольнике и выделять одинаковое место для всех ячеек



                1 



      1     33      33




1     24       12345

Answer (score 1):

Для начала, вам нужно разделить код, занимающийся подсчётом, и код, занимающийся выводом. Не только из эстетических соображений, а и для того, чтобы подсчитать ширину колонки.

Получается вот что:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
    int[][] s = new int [strings][];
    for (int i = 0; i < strings; i++) {  
        s[i] = new int[i+1]; 
        s[i][0] = 1;
        for (int j = 1; j < i; j++) 
            s[i][j] = s[i-1][j-1] + s[i-1][j];
        s[i][i] =  1;
    }

    // найдём самое широкое число
    // по свойству треугольника Паскаля, это число в середине нижнего ряда
    int maxNum = s[strings - 1][(strings - 1)/2];
    int maxNumWidth = Integer.toString(maxNum).length();

    // теперь цикл вывода
    for (int i = 0; i < strings; i++) {
        // насколько ширина данной колонки не дотягивает до наибольшей?
        // для центрирования делим пополам
        int stringPad = (strings - 1 - i) * (maxNumWidth + 1) / 2;
        if (stringPad > 0) // не нашёл лучше способа создать строку пробелов
            System.out.print(String.format("%" + stringPad + "s", ""));
        for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
            String paddedNum = Integer.toString(s[i][j]);
            // центрируем число в своей колонке тоже
            int totalPad = maxNumWidth - paddedNum.length();
            int rPad = totalPad / 2;
            if (rPad > 0)
                paddedNum = String.format("%s%" + rPad + "s", paddedNum, "");
            int lPad = totalPad - rPad;
            if (lPad > 0)
                paddedNum = String.format("%" + lPad + "s%s", "", paddedNum);
            System.out.print(paddedNum);
            if (j < i)
                System.out.print(" ");
            else
                System.out.println();
     }
}
```

Проверка: http://ideone.com/oZKG4u (последние строки съехали из-за ширины поля вывода).